# ERROR Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: react-native, geojson, react-native-maps, mapview

I'm trying to test the `Geojson` library but I'm stuck on this error.

I am sent below my `app.js` and `package.json` codes that was copied from [this repository](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/geojson.md).

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {Geojson} from 'react-native-maps';

const myPlace = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [64.165329, 48.844287],
      }
    }
  ]
};

const Map = props => (
  <MapView>
    <Geojson 
      geojson={myPlace} 
      strokeColor="red"
      fillColor="green"
      strokeWidth={2}
    />
  </MapView>
);
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "geojsonvalidation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.6",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-asset": "^8.9.1",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I'm just trying to validate a possible future solution.

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: Sure,  ERROR  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to export your main comp:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MapView, {Geojson} from 'react-native-maps';

const myPlace = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [64.165329, 48.844287],
      }
    }
  ]
};

const Map = props => (
  <MapView>
    <Geojson 
      geojson={myPlace} 
      strokeColor="red"
      fillColor="green"
      strokeWidth={2}
    />
  </MapView>
);

export default Map; // <——- add this line
```